# Pagination not clickable

Tags: php, mysql, search, pagination

I'm struggeling with the pagination after a search.
This is the code that I'm using as a template:
https://www.sourcecodester.com/php/14194/responsive-online-blog-website-using-phpmysql.html

But this part of the code gives me a headage:

```
if($i==$page){
                $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page current btn-warning" />';
            } else {
                $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page btn-danger" />';
            }
```

Everything works fine but the numbers are not clickable. So there's no way to go to the next page.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Are these submit buttons part of a form, or do they have any JavaScript click handlers attached?

Comment: That is what I find very strange. There's no form or script attached.

Comment: Well then those buttons _can't_ have any effect. A submit button that does not belong to a form does nothing on its own, so if that should have any effect, then it would have to be done via JavaScript.

Comment: But if this is supposed to be a pagination for search results, then most likely it will need sending the search terms to the next page as well (unless they were stored into a session, but that makes rather little sense) - so this probably _should_ be in a form to begin with, that also contains hidden fields to transport the search terms.

Comment: But if you are having problems with a full theme that you just downloaded from somewhere, then you should probably contact the author about that.

Comment: Agree about the author but the theme comes from 2019 and the bug was already reported. I'll delete that part and write my own code.